# Why is Flutter not generating localization files?

Tags: flutter, localization, intl, flutter-localizations, flutter-intl

Whenever I try to run the following commands:

- flutter pub run intl_utils:generate
- flutter gen-l10n
- flutter gen-l10n --template-arb-file=intl_en.arb

It is not able to generate the localization files, throwing an error even when I have created intl_en.arb and other language files as well.

INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_ar, assuming 'ar' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_de, assuming 'de' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_en, assuming 'en' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_es, assuming 'es' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_fr, assuming 'fr' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_id, assuming 'id' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_it, assuming 'it' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_pt, assuming 'pt' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_ro, assuming 'ro' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_sw, assuming 'sw' based on the file name.
INFO: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_tr, assuming 'tr' based on the file name.
**ERROR: Failed to generate localization files.
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**

Comment: you'll need to add ```null``` check on the index variable, see if adding ``` index ?? 0``` works.  Also, provide more details of the code where the index variable is used so that I can think of the solution.

Comment: I haven’t added any of int manually, maybe it’s generating somewhere automatically using flutter_intl.

Comment: try implementing localization with intl package, below doc link can guide you well,
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization?gclsrc=ds 
Avoid using any other plugins for internationalizations.

Comment: "fr": 1 untranslated message(s).
"id": 1 untranslated message(s).
"it": 1 untranslated message(s).
"pt": 1 untranslated message(s).
"ro": 1 untranslated message(s).
"sw": 1 untranslated message(s).
"tr": 1 untranslated message(s).
To see a detailed report, use the untranslated-messages-file 
option in the l10n.yaml file:
untranslated-messages-file: desiredFileName.txt
<other option>: <other selection> 


This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that 
need to be translated.
It gives me this error.